# Saving python list in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to save a python list to mongodb using pymongo, but the saved document has a null value instead of the list.

```
db.testcoll.save({"test" : [12345]})
```

results in

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b53e7b71340f4ad774897a"), "test" : null }
```

A couple of other questions suggested using a dictionary instead, but dict values also result in null.  Both array and dict values work fine when entered directly in the mongo client.  Is this a known gap in the pymongo client?

Comment: Which pymongo version do you use?

Comment: I tried with pymongo version 2.3 and mongo db version 2.2.1 and works fine

Comment: I'm using 2.6 and I encountered the same problem, so it's not just a version issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works well on my *pymongo 2.2.1*. That must have been an issue in the eariler *pymongo* releases. Try to upgrage it.